# Field Not Available for evaluation

Tags: process-builder

I'm evaluating SMS Magic Interact and the goal is to create a Case when an Incoming SMS contains a certain string.

Since, we cannot create records with WorkFlow (unless we use a Flow Trigger, which will be deprecated soon), I'm trying to use Process Builder which allows us to create records.

Unfortunaltely, the Incoming SMS Text field (long text 400) is not available in the criteria wizard.

Is this a bug (long text field) or some other limitation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right SMS Text field is Long text area(32000). Salesforce doesn't allow to use text area / long text area fields in filters also they are not available in SOQL filters (where clause).

You can have work around for this.
Follow below steps for workaround :

1. Create another text field on SMS History object.
2. Create Workflow rule on SMS History object to update field created in step 1. You can use formula which check required string present in SMS Text or not. If present then it will update above field with that value.
3. Now use your process builder for creating Case.

I hope it helps you.
Also let me know if you have any alternative for this other than my workaround.